# Multisample anti-aliasing not working with interior mapping

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

Multisample anti-aliasing is not working for rooms that I generated with [interior mapping](https://www.proun-game.com/Oogst3D/CODING/InteriorMapping/InteriorMapping.pdf) (see the picture below). Any suggestions why this is the case and how it can be resolved?

[image: Room generated with interior mapping]

Comment: By default the pixel shader runs once per pixel, regardless of MSAA. `glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_SHADING)` fixes this, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach, or if you should do AA in the shader instead.

Comment: Multisample antialiasing is for antialiasing geometry edges. It won't antialias harsh edges that arise purely from the choices of what pixel colours you compute in your pixel shader. You'll want to either sample twice and blend in the shader when very close to a corner, or use a post-process antialiasing technique instead.